# CKAN make package private in extension IPackageController after_update

Tags: ckan

In CKAN I am trying to set all datasets to 'Private', so only specific users can publish datasets. I have created an extension and implemented the IPackageController method after_update - this will call the package_update again setting the dataset to private if need be:

```
class SetStateForPendingValidationPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):
   plugins.implements(plugins.IPackageController, inherit=True)

   def after_update(self, context, data_dict):
    log.debug("CKAN after_update context: %r", context)
    log.debug("CKAN after_update data_dict: %r", data_dict)

    # Check if the user is the one who is allowed to publish datasets 

    # Only do this for active datasets, and not ones in draft or deleted state
    # it is also not needed if the dataset is already private
    if 'state' not in data_dict or ( 'state' in data_dict and data_dict['state'] == 'active'):
        if 'private' not in data_dict or ( 'private' in data_dict and data_dict['private'] == False):
            data_dict['private'] = True
            log.info("CKAN to send %r: ", data_dict)
            toolkit.get_action('package_update')(context, data_dict)
```

Unfortunately this crashes the site when being executed with the FileStore turned on, and the user is not an administrator. The dataset is saved correctly, but the system complains when trying to load the page after having saved. It seems to have to do with the file, because when viewing the dataset as an administrator there appears to be no resource, and as an ordinary user the system crashes.

```
[Mon Apr 27 11:45:52 2015] [error] 2015-04-27 11:45:52,079 DEBUG [ckan.logic] check access - user u'nonamin', action resource_create
[Mon Apr 27 11:45:53 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Error - <class 'ckan.logic.NotFound'>:
[Mon Apr 27 11:45:53 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] URL: http://10.11.98.85/dataset/newweekfilepublic
[Mon Apr 27 11:45:53 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weberror/errormiddleware.py', line 162 in __call__
[Mon Apr 27 11:45:53 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   app_iter = self.application(environ, sr_checker)
[Mon Apr 27 11:45:53 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 147 in __call__
```

I have extended the plugin with an IAuthFunctions that always grants the users resource_create, and then it stops crashing. But the file/resource is still not visible.

This seems only to be relevant when creating a dataset. Adding resources/files afterwards seems to works as intended.